# embedded a dialog in a tab control. but it's not in tab control

Tags: mfc

this's my source:

```
void CCCRView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
.
.
.
    VERIFY(dlg1.Create(CaaaqweqweqweDlg::IDD, this));
    VERIFY(dlg1.SetWindowPos(GetDlgItem(IDC_TAB2),100, 100,200, 200, SWP_SHOWWINDOW|SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_NOMOVE));
    dlg1.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}
```

with: 
IDC_TAB2: is the tab control..............
dlg1:my dialog i want embedded in....................................
CaaaqweqweqweDlg: name of class dialog.(CaaaqweqweqweDlg dlg1;)...............................................

this is my desin:

[image]

This is my result:
[image]

We can see the dialog don't in tab control.
Somebody help me? thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You must change the dialog style to `CHILD`. You probably have the `POPUP` style set.

Answer (score 0):

Dialogs or other controls are not children of the tab, they are children of whatever window the tab itself is on, too. What you do is you use CTabCtrl's AdjustRect() to calculate the position of the content of the tabs. Plus you have to manually manage tab changes and handle what to do (generally, that means hiding everything except the control you want to be part of the tab).

Historically you'd write your own abstraction over CTabCtrl so that it can contain controls or windows and that you could decouple the tab from the window it's on. However since MFC Next there is a CMFCTabCtrl that behaves like you are expecting, so use that and you'll be good.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place the child dialog properly you have to:

- get the reference tab control position to place the dialog correctly
- remove the SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_NOMOVE to apply this position

It would look to something like this (untested):

```
dlg1.Create(CaaaqweqweqweDlg::IDD, this);

CRect Rect;
GetDlgItem(IDC_TAB2)->GetWindowRect(Rect);
Rect.InflateRect(-10, -10);
ScreenToClient(Rect);

dlg1.SetWindowPos(&wndTop, Rect.left, Rect.top, Rect.Width(), Rect.Height(), SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

The `wndTop` will make sure that the dialog is on top of any other control.